# Cloud database service for android application

Tags: android, database-design

I'm trying to write an android app that contains list of notes and sync them between other users (for example, if two users use the app and one of them update the list the second will get the updated automatically). I read about mongoDB and I'm trying to use it for this propose  (I'm looking for a free service cause I'm in a study period). can I use mongoDB to implement it? is there something simpler? I read about the REST api and I didn't understand how should I work with that.. why does all the example with mongoDB appears with localhost url? it should be a cloud service isn't it? I opened an account and I'm trying to use it from my android app by sending GET request without success.. Am i missing something? should I implement a server side too?

Thanks in advance

Comment: localhost url? it should be a cloud service isn't it? what ?! O.o , Start To Learn Here http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions.html

Comment: why didn't you give me link for www.gooogle.com ? i already built my first andoird app - I'm trying to learn how to integrate my app in the cloud, can u help me with that please?

Answer (score 1):

First let me lighten up some thing ,

Did u know how to write web services ( whatever language or api ) !?

Did u know server side javascript ( Nodejs ) ?

It doesn't matter , you should write down a webservice to store and retrieve your data for example in json format then in your apk you just use it ( ui , edit , etc ) , then u will pass it to your webservice ,

NOW About MongoDB

mongoDB was developed for cloud environments so u can , but as today i think cloudfoundry http://www.cloudfoundry.com/ is only stable environment which support mongoDB as one of their data services , so signup for cloud foundry and get started

you need to some knowledge with node.js OR php OR python to work with cloudfoundry

[Some apps with source](http://support.cloudfoundry.com/entries/20158287-cool-apps-on-cloud-foundry)

i know this [person](http://twitter.com/#!/kumi360) , he is too kind to lead lead u

---

AND

Search and ask for , how to make php web service for mongodb ?!

How to use web services in android ?!

Some parts of your questions ( Localhost ) , is like you don't have any idea on web based apps !

First Step

**Create a WebService in PHP / MongoDB** ( cause there is a lot of resources on php ) to Store and Retrieve Data in anyway ( Json is better cause it's easy to work within android )

Then ask for other parts !

Comment: I'm trying to understand the big picture. isn't it enough to build a client app in android that could communicate with MongoDB by REST API?  is mongoDB act like a server or should I implement/use other server?

Comment: by the way, mongoDB is not a restriction, I just read few words about them and I saw that they offer 240MB free.. I also read that it a NoSql DB which mean nothing to me... (I know mySql & Sqlite) so if you can recommend me about other free service it will be great